# What is the style of search used in Sublime Text Command Pallette called?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, string-matching

I have a simple question.. I want to know what a style of searching is referred to as, like how may I refer to this style of searching when I am researching it.

In Sublime Text 3 when you hit Ctrl+ Shift + P the command pallette pops up, and you are able to type in a search query... Now, the special thing about this Sublime Text find box is that it will find search results based on the number of matched characters in sequence, rather than the strict name of the file. So, something like "packcon" will bring up "Package Control" and then something like "synrub" will bring up "Syntax: Ruby".

What is this style of string matching called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fuzzy Matching` is the common name but more correctly referred to as `Approximate String Matching`.

More to read here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I spent so long googling this, I heard the term  while watching a sublime tutorial and then forgot it. Thank you!